# Failing deploying to AWS Elasticbeanstalk: rb_sysopen - /var/elasticbeanstalk/staging/httpd/./conf.d

Tags: apache, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am deploying my war file to AWS Elastic Beanstalk.
The goal is to switch to HTTPS, but the deployment fails. How this should be solved?
Inside the war I have:
/.ebextensions/httpd/conf/httpd.conf file which is the same as original one, but with added module.

/.ebextensions/httpd/conf.d/80.conf which looks like that:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
   LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so

   RewriteEngine On
   RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https
   RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !ELB-HealthChecker
   RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}

   <Proxy *>
       Order deny,allow
       Allow from all
   </Proxy>

   ProxyPass / http://localhost:8080/ retry=0
   ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:8080/
   ProxyPreserveHost on

   ErrorLog /var/log/httpd/elasticbeanstalk-error_log

</VirtualHost>
```

/.ebextensions/https-instance.config which looks like that:

```
packages:
  yum:
    mod_ssl : []

files:
  /etc/pki/tls/certs/server.crt:
    mode: "000400"
    owner: root
    group: root
    content: |
      -----BEGIN CERTIFICATE----- 
      -----END CERTIFICATE-----

  /etc/pki/tls/certs/server.key:
    mode: "000400"
    owner: root
    group: root
    content: |
      -----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----

      -----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----

container_commands:
  killhttpd:
    command: "/sbin/service httpd stop"
  waitforhttpddeath:
    command: "sleep 3"
```

During deployment I have an error which is shown in /var/log/eb-activity.log like that:

> /opt/elasticbeanstalk/lib/ruby/lib/ruby/2.2.0/fileutils.rb:1392:in
>   `initialize': Is a directory @ rb_sysopen -
>   /var/elasticbeanstalk/staging/httpd/./conf.d (Errno::EISDIR)      from
>   /opt/elasticbeanstalk/lib/ruby/lib/ruby/2.2.0/fileutils.rb:1392:in`
>   open'    from
>   /opt/elasticbeanstalk/lib/ruby/lib/ruby/2.2.0/fileutils.rb:1392:in
>   `block in copy_file'      from
>   /opt/elasticbeanstalk/lib/ruby/lib/ruby/2.2.0/fileutils.rb:1391:in`
>   open'    from
>   /opt/elasticbeanstalk/lib/ruby/lib/ruby/2.2.0/fileutils.rb:1391:in
>   `copy_file'       from
>   /opt/elasticbeanstalk/lib/ruby/lib/ruby/2.2.0/fileutils.rb:1359:in`
>   copy'    from
>   /opt/elasticbeanstalk/lib/ruby/lib/ruby/2.2.0/fileutils.rb:471:in
>   `block in copy_entry'     from
>   /opt/elasticbeanstalk/lib/ruby/lib/ruby/2.2.0/fileutils.rb:1497:in`
>   call'    from
>   /opt/elasticbeanstalk/lib/ruby/lib/ruby/2.2.0/fileutils.rb:1497:in
>   `wrap_traverse'       from
>   /opt/elasticbeanstalk/lib/ruby/lib/ruby/2.2.0/fileutils.rb:1500:in`
>   block in wrap_traverse'      from
>   /opt/elasticbeanstalk/lib/ruby/lib/ruby/2.2.0/fileutils.rb:1499:in
>   `each'    from
>   /opt/elasticbeanstalk/lib/ruby/lib/ruby/2.2.0/fileutils.rb:1499:in`
>   wrap_traverse'       from
>   /opt/elasticbeanstalk/lib/ruby/lib/ruby/2.2.0/fileutils.rb:468:in
>   `copy_entry'      from
>   /opt/elasticbeanstalk/lib/ruby/lib/ruby/2.2.0/fileutils.rb:443:in`
>   block in cp_r'       from
>   /opt/elasticbeanstalk/lib/ruby/lib/ruby/2.2.0/fileutils.rb:1570:in
>   `block in fu_each_src_dest'       from
>   /opt/elasticbeanstalk/lib/ruby/lib/ruby/2.2.0/fileutils.rb:1584:in`
>   fu_each_src_dest0'       from
>   /opt/elasticbeanstalk/lib/ruby/lib/ruby/2.2.0/fileutils.rb:1568:in
>   `fu_each_src_dest'    from
>   /opt/elasticbeanstalk/lib/ruby/lib/ruby/2.2.0/fileutils.rb:442:in`
>   cp_r'    from
>   /opt/elasticbeanstalk/private/lib/proxy_support/httpd22.rb:121:in
>   `configure_httpd'     from
>   /opt/elasticbeanstalk/private/lib/proxy_support/httpd22.rb:39:in`
>   block in configure'      from
>   /opt/elasticbeanstalk/private/lib/component.rb:10:in `call'       from
>   /opt/elasticbeanstalk/private/lib/component.rb:10:in`configure'
>     from /opt/elasticbeanstalk/private/lib/proxy_support/httpd22.rb:22:in
>   `configure'       from /opt/elasticbeanstalk/private/lib/proxy.rb:19:in`
>   block in configure'      from
>   /opt/elasticbeanstalk/private/lib/component.rb:10:in `call'       from
>   /opt/elasticbeanstalk/private/lib/component.rb:10:in`configure'
>     from /opt/elasticbeanstalk/private/lib/proxy.rb:17:in `configure'
>
>     from /opt/elasticbeanstalk/bin/proxy:46:in`'
>   (Executor::NonZeroExitStatus)